# How to deal with IIS sub applications using MVC routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC application that has been moved to a sub folder in the wwwroot, and this sub folder has been made an application via IIS. So whereas before the url to my login page would look like this:

**www.mydomain.com/login**

It now looks like this:

**www.mydomain.com/application/login**

The application works fine, it doesn't seem to have affected the routing or any of the links in my application. However, it is causing problems where I am referencing image src's like so:

```
<img src="/content/images/myimage.png"/>
```

As it is attempting to retrieve the image from the url **www.mydomain.com/content/images/myimage.png** which obviously returns a 404.

In my global.asax file I am only using the default route, which I have attempted to modify to account for the subfolder as part of the url:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
                "application/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "dashboard", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

However, now when I attempt to go to the root url **www.mydomain.com/application** I just get a directory listing! And if I try to go directly to controller i.e  **www.mydomain.com/application/dashboard** I get a 404!

Anyone got any idea how to deal with this situation via MVC routing?

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need to change your routing. It works from entry point to your app.
2. Use @Url.Content("~/content/images/myimage.png").

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeh I know I could use Url.Content but my site is large and I don't want to go and change all the image references to use Url.Content!

Comment: You can create T4 template to update them for you=) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: cool didn't know about T4 templating, sounds useful I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
routes.MapRoute("Application",
                "application/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "dashboard", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "dashboard", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: That won't work for this scenario because static files don't get routed. They are handled by the StaticFileHandler (IHttpHandler).

Comment: when I try this, all razor ActionLink uses show the anchor url starting with 'Application' even when no route value is supplied in the ActionLink

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit of knowledge here that I too tried to create multiple subapplications under a single site. All of the .js Ajax calls broke as the URLs were set to look at the root directory "/Controller/Method". The fix (which I abandoned) was to prefix each URL with the subapplication/subfolder name or create a "universal" .js variable to set the subapplication and append to the URL as a prefix.